# What happened to the reputation information box design?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my reputation information box.

The green +5 next to the 1,892 seems a bit too high. The numbers on the graph also look not quite right, and in fact, looking at the tooltip when moving over it, it is in the wrong place numerically.

It happens on both Firefox and Google Chrome.

Comment: Are you viewing this on a Nokia 3118?

Comment: @random No, on a computer. Your graph looks similiar to me.

Comment: Repro'ed on Win10 Chrome

Comment: Same on OSX Safari.  Top label on the graph is okay, the lower two are up too high.

Comment: Seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed.

The graph labels and the rep change notice are now in their original place.