# The reputation infobox is broken again, but now just on beta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, design, beta-sites

A few months ago, I reported this bug: [What happened to the reputation information box design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270462/what-happened-to-the-reputation-information-box-design)

From the other question (paraphrased):

> The green +17 next to the 311 seems a bit too high. The numbers on the graph also look not quite right, and in fact, looking at the tooltip when moving over it, it is in the wrong place numerically.

However, it has been broken again, but now just on beta (both private and public) sites:

[image] [image]

Comment: what is broken about this? it's not obvious

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. This has been fixed and should be updated on production now.